# laravel 5.2 URL background in css

Tags: css, laravel-5

I am using a template in the css there is the line:

```
background: url('/images/bg.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
```

How should I do this in Laravel? The css is in the public  directory:

```
<link href="{{URL::to('/style.css" rel="stylesheet')}}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout out the [assert](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-asset) helper function

```
<link href="{{ asset('style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```